# Why _set.all dont work in tempale?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I have 3 connected with each other models. `GroupRequirementType --> GroupRequirement --> Requirement`. I am tring to show all requirements in template. Next code show me only GroupRequirementType objects. It seems like I have problems with `_set.all`. Whats wrong?

**models.py:**

```
class GroupRequirementType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class GroupRequirement(models.Model):
    group_requirement_type = models.ForeignKey(GroupRequirementType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Requirement(models.Model):
    group_requirement = models.ForeignKey(GroupRequirement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**template:**

```
{% for group_requirement_type in group_requirement_types %}
   {{ group_requirement_type }}

   {% for group_requirement in group_requirement_type.group_requirement_set.all %} <!--DONT WORK. WHY?-->
      {{ group_requirement }}

      {% for requirement in group_requirement.requirement_set.all %}
         {{ requirement }}
      {% endfor %}

   {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't remember if Django automatically converts CamelCase to lowercase by adding an underscore. Does `grouprequirement_set.all` work?

Comment: Thank you! You was right. `grouprequirement_set.all` works. Post your answer again pls but not as comment. I will mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Django doesn't automatically add an underscore when converting the CamelCase model name to lower case. `grouprequirement_set.all` works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using Django ForeignKey `related_name` property in your models declaration, this makes backwards relations operations much easier: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

In your case it will turn into something like

**models.py:**

```
class GroupRequirementType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class GroupRequirement(models.Model):
    group_requirement_type = models.ForeignKey(GroupRequirementType, related_name='group_requirements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Requirement(models.Model):
    group_requirement = models.ForeignKey(GroupRequirement, related_name='requirements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**template:**

```
{% for group_requirement_type in group_requirement_types %}
    {{ group_requirement_type }}

    {% for group_requirement in group_requirement_type.group_requirements.all %} <!--DONT WORK. WHY?-->
        {{ group_requirement }}

        {% for requirement in group_requirement.requirements.all %}
            {{ requirement }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```